# Removing style sheet from index.html

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I was experimenting a component for my React app so I had to include the following stylesheets in my index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

After that, I was unable to get rid of them.  Even though I removed those codes from index.html but I can still see them from Chrome inspector. I cleared everything for my app but those lines still exist.  Why is that?  How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove chrome cache. Go to Network and Disable Cache on developer window. If doesn't work remove cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually did a clean up before but it didn't do anything.  I found out I had to restart npm to make the code to forget the links.